# How to back up machine in amazon web services

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm new in amazon web services and I'm still trying how to use it...I just 
  want 
  to know how can I back a machine in amazon web services?

Answer (score 0):

You have several options.  First and foremost, I would recommend periodically taking a ["snapshot"](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-creating-snapshot.html).

If you have Wordpress, I would recommend getting a backup plugin.  These are useful for "backups" per se; they can *ALSO* be helpful migrating a WP site from "test" to "development".  Personally, I use [Updraft Plus](https://wordpress.org/plugins/updraftplus/).

Beyond that, here are some good alternatives for backing up EC2 instances:

- [How to Back Up Amazon EC2 Instances](https://www.cloudberrylab.com/resources/blog/backup-aws-ec2-instance/)

And are are some alternatives for backing up a Linux system in general:

- [Top 5 System Backup Tools for the Linux Desktop ( Updated 2019)](https://zillowtech.com/system-backup-tools-for-linux.html)

Comment: @user2983509 thank you so much I'll try those solutions :)

Answer (score 0):

Best way to manage the machine backup is taking a snapshot of your EBS volume. you can schedule the backup for multiple EBS

You can follow this links for reference

Snapshot using AWS console : [link](https://hackernoon.com/automating-ebs-snapshots-in-aws-b8401fe40353)

Snapshot using CLI (if you would like to explore) : [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/create-snapshot.html)